# rails 3 - complete disable the i18n fallbacks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, fallback

Is it possible to disable the i18n fallbacks complete?

Also the "translation" of the model attribute names. 
i.e. `<%= f.label :title %>` gets "translated" to Title. I want an error message there...

I've set up `config.i18n.fallbacks = false` in my initializer, but the model's attribute names are still there.

Comment: How are you setting the error message in this case? I know that this doesn't answer your question, but… You're not forced to use the label helper or the automatically set label content. Even with the helper you can provide your own content `<%= f.label :title, "foo" %> Otherwise, why not use plain HTML?

Comment: You're right. Maybe i should just use my own translations...

Comment: What you're seeing is the html generated for this no-translation-error, e.g.

    <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.some.key.title">Title</span>

Comment: One option is to [redefine the exception handler](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-exception-handlers)